# Swap two URLs with each other

Tags: .htaccess

I have two pages:

- http:// example.com containing content generated by CMS
- http:// example.com/static-page/10 which is static page created in CMS

I would like to show my static page under main address (http:// example.com) and do it without redirecting (so user wouldn't see /static-page/10 in URL) and display my current main page in URL for example http:// example.com/info.
Is it possible?
Thanks in advance.
PS: reputation doesn't allow me to post multiple links, so I have broken them with a space

Update:
My current .htaccess (generated by CMS):

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$ 
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$

RewriteRule ^webapi/net-soap.*$ api.php?objects=1 [QSA,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^webapi/soap.*$ api.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^webapi/json.*$ api.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^webapi/rest.*$ api.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: What redirects did you have already try ?

Comment: I have tried: RewriteRule ^/?$  http://example.com/test.html [NC,END]
with different flags, but it simply redirects example.com to example.com/test.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this i am assuming index.php your main site index

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^$ /static-page/10
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l        
RewriteRule ^info$ index.php
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately it didn't work. Your code alone caused no file found error and combined with existing .htaccess didn't have any impact. I have updated my question with existing .htaccess - sorry, that I didn't think about it earlier.

Comment: what is `/static-page/10` and what is index file of root?

Comment: If I am correct all pages in this CMS are created through index.php. Static page is main layout + content downloaded from database record.

Comment: from your current htaccess i am unable to get hint do you have root .htaccess from which cms is passing value to index.php

Comment: It is the root .htaccess. Other .htaccesses contain only "order" and "deny" commands.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like that :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ /info
RewriteRule ^static-page/10$ /
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately it didn't work. Your code alone caused no file found error and combined with existing .htaccess didn't have any impact. I have updated my question with existing .htaccess - sorry, that I didn't think about it earlier.

Comment: Try to add these two lines to the end of your .htaccess file :
RewriteRule ^info$ index.php
RewriteRule ^$ static-page/10

but be sure to check your CMS link to check if this didnt brake any other links

Comment: Basic address doesn't redirect to anything (still main page) and /info redirects to main page, but changes URL.